# change backgrooun-image usingdocument.getElementByClassName

Tags: javascript

Attached is my code where I want background image of a div to be selected by js:

```
<html lang = "en">
<head>
  <title>to-forum.html</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
  .logo 
  {
    width:1200px;
    height:300px;
    margin:auto;
    display: block; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    border-radius: 25px;
  }
  </style>
    <script>
      function ChangeImage(param)
      { 
        switch(param)
        {
          case '1':
            return("images/greensilver.gif");
            break;
          case'2':              
            return("images/greensilver1.gif");
            break;
        }
      }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="logo"> 
    <script>
      document.getElementByClassName("logo").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + ChangeImage('1') + "')";
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The image doesn't show up ! Could anyone show me how to correct the code ?
Thanks

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Please refer to [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you tried to do any research? What have you tried? Questions here should have a clear problem/question, with research shown, and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 2):

You have used `id logo` but you are trying to access `logo div` using className. which is wrong. Use document.getElementById("logo").

```
document.getElementById("logo").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + ChangeImage('1') + "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax wrong**

1. classname is the multiple one `getElements` .its have plural form
2. And mention `[0]`.Then only it target first classname

Change like this

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("logo")[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('" + ChangeImage('1') + "')";
```

Instead of

```
document.getElementByClassName("logo").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + ChangeImage('1') + "')";
```